# Why does pycharm give "expected type" warning for None outside a class or function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Why does pycharm give "expected type" warning for `None` outside a class or function in this code:

```
def blah():
    hiya = None  # type: dict   # No type warning

class Foo:
    bar = None  # type: dict    # No type warning

asf = None  # type: dict        # Expected type 'dict', got 'None' instead
```

Comment: please tag all python questions with the generic [python] tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Pycharm and this works for me just fine

```
def blah():
hiya = None  # type: #dict   # No type warning

class Foo:
    bar = None  # type: #dict    # No type warning

asf = None  # type: #dict        # Expected type 'dict', got 'None' instead
```

maybe it's something in your settings.

Comment: you're saying you *don't* get an "expected type" warning on the `asf` line? What version of pycharm and python are you using? I'm on pycharm pro 2019.1 and python 3.7.1

Comment: version of pycharm = 2019.1.2 and python doesn't matter just 3.7